# Retrieve all cells with values that end in a specific text string

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to retrieve the cells out of a value comparison? Let me explain:

Lets say I have a cell column named "Codes" and the multi-cell range contains the following values:

- AS12G
- A25LM
- T5S0O
- NBTLM
- 55EWO
- EVOLM
- EXCLM
- VBT7S
- T82LM

How can I retrieve the cells that end up in 'LM'?

So that I can capture the values: A25LM, NBTLM, EVOLM, EXCLM, T82LM

Comment: Will "LM" always be the final two characters? If so, perhaps looping through each cell, evaluating the final two characters, and depositing the cell addresses for valid hits into an array?

Comment: Yes, LM will always be for the final two characters. But the thing is if there is any way to do it faster than looping, perhaps an excel function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example for column **C**

```
Sub LM_Getter()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, mesage As String, kolumn As Long

    kolumn = 3 'column C
    mesage = ""
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, kolumn).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        t = Cells(i, kolumn).Text
        If Right(t, 2) = "LM" Then
            mesage = mesage & "," & t
        End If
    Next i
    If mesage <> "" Then
        mesage = Mid(mesage, 2)
    End If
    MsgBox mesage
End Sub
```

The captured list may be stored for later use.

Comment: I understand this that every cell that matches the condition is stored as a chained text, but what is that If mesage not empty for?

Comment: @Mayhem .............if *mesage* is not empty, then the code removes the leading comma.

Answer (score 0):

Since no VBA code is posted, I assume the desired solution is cell-formula based. Here is what it can be. Assume your data is in column "A:A", startin in "A1". Enter this formula into "B1": `=IF(RIGHT(A1,2)="LM",A1,"")` and copy it down.